# check particular node is exist or not in XML using vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript, xml-parsing

This is my XML file :

```
<ECSC>
   <ATTRIBUTES>
      <some part of attribute section>
   </ATTRIBUTES>
   <SCRIPT>
      <ETXML_LINE_TABTYPE>
         <some part of script section>                 
      </ETXML_LINE_TABTYPE>
   </SCRIPT>
   <PARAMETERS>
      <ETPAR_GUIX>
         <item>
            <PNAME>I_LANG</PNAME>
            <PTYP>I</PTYP>
            <PINDEX>0003</PINDEX>
            <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
            <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
            <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
            <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
            <SORT_LNR>0001</SORT_LNR>
            <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
         </item>
         <item>
            <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_1</PNAME>
            <PTYP>X</PTYP>
            <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
            <PINDEX>0009</PINDEX>
            <PGROUP>SAPGUI</PGROUP>
            <XMLREF_TYP>G</XMLREF_TYP>
            <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
            <PREF_NAME>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME>
            <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
            <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
            <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
            <SORT_LNR>0001</SORT_LNR>
            <PREF_NAME2>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME2>
            <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
            <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
            <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
         </item>
         <item>
            <PNAME>V_LANG</PNAME>
            <PTYP>V</PTYP>
            <PINDEX>0007</PINDEX>
            <PGROUP>V.01</PGROUP>
            <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
            <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
            <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
            <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
            <SORT_LNR>0002</SORT_LNR>
            <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
         </item>
         <item>
            <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_2</PNAME>
            <PTYP>X</PTYP>
            <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
            <PINDEX>0010</PINDEX>
            <PGROUP>SAPGUI</PGROUP>
            <XMLREF_TYP>G</XMLREF_TYP>
            <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
            <PREF_NAME>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME>
            <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
            <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
            <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
            <SORT_LNR>0002</SORT_LNR>
            <PREF_NAME2>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME2>
            <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
            <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
            <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
         </item>
         <item>
            <PNAME>I_AGENT</PNAME>
            <PTYP>I</PTYP>
            <PINDEX>0002</PINDEX>
            <PGROUP>I.03</PGROUP>
            <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
            <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
            <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
            <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
            <SORT_LNR>0003</SORT_LNR>
            <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
         </item>
         <item>
            <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_3</PNAME>
            <PTYP>X</PTYP>
            <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
            <PINDEX>0011</PINDEX>
            <PGROUP>GETGUI</PGROUP>
            <XMLREF_TYP>I</XMLREF_TYP>
            <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
            <PREF_NAME>GETGUI</PREF_NAME>
            <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
            <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
            <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
            <SORT_LNR>0003</SORT_LNR>
            <PREF_NAME2>GETGUI</PREF_NAME2>
            <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
            <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
            <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
         </item>
         <item>
            <PNAME>I_TYPE</PNAME>
            <PTYP>I</PTYP>
            <PINDEX>0004</PINDEX>
            <PGROUP>V.04</PGROUP>
            <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
            <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
            <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
            <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
            <SORT_LNR>0004</SORT_LNR>
            <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
         </item>
         <item>
            <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_4</PNAME>
            <PTYP>X</PTYP>
            <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
            <PINDEX>0012</PINDEX>
            <PGROUP>GETGUI</PGROUP>
            <XMLREF_TYP>I</XMLREF_TYP>
            <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
            <PREF_NAME>GETGUI</PREF_NAME>
            <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
            <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
            <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
            <SORT_LNR>0004</SORT_LNR>
            <PREF_NAME2>GETGUI</PREF_NAME2>
            <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
            <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
            <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
         </item>
         <item>
            <PNAME>V_AGENT</PNAME>
            <PTYP>V</PTYP>
            <PINDEX>0006</PINDEX>
            <PGROUP>I.02</PGROUP>
            <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
            <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
            <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
            <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
            <SORT_LNR>0005</SORT_LNR>
            <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
         </item>
         <item>
            <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_5</PNAME>
            <PTYP>X</PTYP>
            <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
            <PINDEX>0013</PINDEX>
            <PGROUP>GETGUI</PGROUP>
            <XMLREF_TYP>I</XMLREF_TYP>
            <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
            <PREF_NAME>GETGUI</PREF_NAME>
            <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
            <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
            <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
            <SORT_LNR>0005</SORT_LNR>
            <PREF_NAME2>GETGUI</PREF_NAME2>
            <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
            <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
            <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
         </item>
         <item>
            <PNAME>V_TYPE</PNAME>
            <PTYP>V</PTYP>
            <PINDEX>0008</PINDEX>
            <PGROUP>V.03</PGROUP>
            <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
            <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
            <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
            <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
            <SORT_LNR>0006</SORT_LNR>
            <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
         </item>
         <item>
            <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_6</PNAME>
            <PTYP>X</PTYP>
            <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
            <PINDEX>0014</PINDEX>
            <PGROUP>SAPGUI</PGROUP>
            <XMLREF_TYP>G</XMLREF_TYP>
            <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
            <PREF_NAME>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME>
            <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
            <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
            <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
            <SORT_LNR>0006</SORT_LNR>
            <PREF_NAME2>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME2>
            <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
            <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
            <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
         </item>
         <item>
            <PNAME>MSG_1</PNAME>
            <PTYP>X</PTYP>
            <PDESC>Rules for Message Check eCATT Command MESSAGE</PDESC>
            <PINDEX>0005</PINDEX>
            <PGROUP>MESSAGE</PGROUP>
            <XMLREF_TYP>M</XMLREF_TYP>
            <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
            <PREF_NAME>ETMSG_DEF_TABTYPE</PREF_NAME>
            <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
            <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
            <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
            <SORT_LNR>0007</SORT_LNR>
            <PREF_NAME2>ETMSG_DEF_TABTYPE</PREF_NAME2>
            <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
            <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
         </item>
         <item>
            <PNAME>E_MSG_1</PNAME>
            <PTYP>X</PTYP>
            <PDESC>Collected Messages Before ENDMESSAGE</PDESC>
            <PINDEX>0001</PINDEX>
            <PGROUP>ENDMESSAGE</PGROUP>
            <XMLREF_TYP>N</XMLREF_TYP>
            <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
            <PREF_NAME>ETMSG_RES_TABTYPE</PREF_NAME>
            <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
            <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
            <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
            <SORT_LNR>0008</SORT_LNR>
            <PREF_NAME2>ETMSG_RES_TABTYPE</PREF_NAME2>
            <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
            <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
         </item>
         <item>
            <PNAME>ZX_FI_FP_0569_MS07_COAS_FB_1</PNAME>
            <PTYP>X</PTYP>
            <PDESC>TF_FI_FP_FI_0569_MS07_CO_Search_Help_Internal_Orders_vTD0_1_</PDESC>
            <PINDEX>0015</PINDEX>
            <PGROUP>REF</PGROUP>
            <XMLREF_TYP>R</XMLREF_TYP>
            <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
            <PREF_NAME>ZX_FI_FP_0569_MS07_COAS_FB01</PREF_NAME>
            <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
            <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
            <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
            <SORT_LNR>0009</SORT_LNR>
            <PREF_NAME2>ZX_FI_FP_0569_MS07_COAS_FB01</PREF_NAME2>
            <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
            <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
         </item>
      </ETPAR_GUIX>
   </PARAMETERS>
</ECSC>
```

I want to check in above XML file in `<PARAMETER>` tag nodeName `<PGROUP>` is exist or NOT..? 
For example In `<PARAMETER>` tag for `<PNAME>I_LANG</PNAME>` item does not have tag or nodeName like `<PGROUP>` so in this situation VB script should display error.

For `<PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_1</PNAME>` the nodeName `<PGROUP>` tag is exist so this is correct  In this way I want to check for which `<PNAME>` the `<PGROUP>` tag is not exist.

I have tried following vbscript :

```
Dim oFS      : Set oFS      = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sFSpec   : sFSpec       =        oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("C:\sample.xml")
Dim objMSXML : Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
objMSXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
objMSXML.async = False
objMSXML.load sFSpec
objMSXML.validateOnParse = True  
counter=0
Set  NodeList =      objMSXML.documentElement.selectNodes("/ECSC/PARAMETERS/ETPAR_GUIX/item/PGROUP")
for each item in NodeList
myPNAME = objMSXML.getElementsByTagName("PNAME").item(counter).text
If (Left(myPNAME,1)="I") Then
    If objMSXML.getElementsByTagName("PNAME").item(counter).nodeName = "PGROUP" Then
        msgbox("PGROUP is exist for" &myPNAME)
    Else
        msgbox("PGROUP is NOT exist for" &myPNAME)
    End If
End If
counter=counter+1
  Next
```

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [format your XML properly](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html#ad-output) next time!

Answer (score 0):

Using this XPath you'll get all `<PNAME>` which doesn't have corresponding `<PGROUGP>` :

```
/ECSC/PARAMETERS/ETPAR_GUIX/item[not(PGROUP)]/PNAME
```

This way you're sure that each `item` in `NodeList` must be without `<PGROUP>` :

```
Set NodeList = objMSXML.documentElement.selectNodes("/ECSC/PARAMETERS/ETPAR_GUIX/item[not(PGROUP)]/PNAME")
```

Comment: Yes this is right but it takes only first two items only from `<PARAMETERS>` tag. Its not able to find all `<PNAME>` which doesn't have any corresponding `<PGROUP>`. please help me. Thank you

Comment: This worked fine given XML input as you posted in question. No one can help further unless you can provide sample XML that failed using this XPath (and explain how does it particularly fails given such XML sample)

Comment: Yes this is right in above given XML file only `<PNAME>I_LANG</PNAME>` this node doesn't have any corresponding `<PGROUP>` node But if I want to find all `<PNAME>` nodes who doesn't having `<PGROUP>` so I tried by using above code but It does not give any ans except `<PNAME>I_LANG</PNAME>` please help

Comment: Read my comment again, for this very question this answer worked fine. If you need different solution, you should've posted an example XML that confirm so

Comment: Hi I have updated XML file and Vb script code also the Following XML `<PNAME>`node doesn't have corresponding `<PGROUP>` 1)`<PNAME>I_LANG</PNAME>` 2)`<PNAME>V_LANG</PNAME>` 3)`<PNAME>I_AGENT</PNAME>` 4)`<PNAME>I_TYPE</PNAME>` for these VB script should display error but I tried with your provided solution it only displaying error for `<PNAME>I_LANG</PNAME>` not for others. Please help me