# Check XML node exist or not using vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript, xml-parsing

This is my XML file

```
<ECSC>
<ATTRIBUTES>
     < some part of attribute section >
</ATTRIBUTES>
<SCRIPT>
  <ETXML_LINE_TABTYPE>
     <some part of script section>                 
  </ETXML_LINE_TABTYPE>
</SCRIPT>
<PARAMETERS>
  <ETPAR_GUIX>
     <item>
        <PNAME>I_LANG</PNAME>
        <PTYP>I</PTYP>
        <PINDEX>0003</PINDEX>
        <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
        <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
        <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0001</SORT_LNR>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_1</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0009</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>SAPGUI</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>G</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0001</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME2>
        <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>V_LANG</PNAME>
        <PTYP>V</PTYP>
        <PINDEX>0007</PINDEX>

        <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
        <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
        <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0002</SORT_LNR>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_2</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0010</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>SAPGUI</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>G</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0002</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME2>
        <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>I_AGENT</PNAME>
        <PTYP>I</PTYP>
        <PINDEX>0002</PINDEX>

        <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
        <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
        <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0003</SORT_LNR>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_3</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0011</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>GETGUI</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>I</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>GETGUI</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0003</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>GETGUI</PREF_NAME2>
        <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>I_TYPE</PNAME>
        <PTYP>I</PTYP>
        <PINDEX>0004</PINDEX>

        <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
        <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
        <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0004</SORT_LNR>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_4</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0012</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>GETGUI</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>I</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>GETGUI</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0004</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>GETGUI</PREF_NAME2>
        <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>V_AGENT</PNAME>
        <PTYP>V</PTYP>
        <PINDEX>0006</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>I.02</PGROUP>
        <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
        <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
        <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0005</SORT_LNR>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_5</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0013</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>GETGUI</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>I</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>GETGUI</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0005</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>GETGUI</PREF_NAME2>
        <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>V_TYPE</PNAME>
        <PTYP>V</PTYP>
        <PINDEX>0008</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>V.03</PGROUP>
        <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
        <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
        <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0006</SORT_LNR>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_6</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0014</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>SAPGUI</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>G</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0006</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME2>
        <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>MSG_1</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>Rules for Message Check eCATT Command MESSAGE</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0005</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>MESSAGE</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>M</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>ETMSG_DEF_TABTYPE</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0007</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>ETMSG_DEF_TABTYPE</PREF_NAME2>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>E_MSG_1</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>Collected Messages Before ENDMESSAGE</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0001</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>ENDMESSAGE</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>N</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>ETMSG_RES_TABTYPE</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0008</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>ETMSG_RES_TABTYPE</PREF_NAME2>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>ZX_FI_FP_0569_MS07_COAS_FB_1</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>TF_FI_FP_FI_0569_MS07_CO_Search_Help_Internal_Orders_vTD0_1_</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0015</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>REF</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>R</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>ZX_FI_FP_0569_MS07_COAS_FB01</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0009</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>ZX_FI_FP_0569_MS07_COAS_FB01</PREF_NAME2>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
  </ETPAR_GUIX>
```

I want to check in above XML file in  tag nodeName  is exist or NOT..? For example In `<PARAMETER>` tag for `<PNAME>I_LANG</PNAME>` item does not have tag or nodeName like `<PGROUP>` so in this situation VB script should display error.

For `<PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_1</PNAME>` the nodeName `<PGROUP>` tag is exist so this is correct In this way I want to check for which `<PNAME>` the `<PGROUP>` tag is not exist.

The following XML `<PNAME>` node doesn't have corresponding `<PGROUP>` 
1)`<PNAME>I_LANG</PNAME>` 
2)`<PNAME>V_LANG</PNAME>` 
3)`<PNAME>I_AGENT</PNAME>` 
4)`<PNAME>I_TYPE</PNAME>`
    for these VB script should display error but I tried with following vb script it only displaying error for `<PNAME>I_LANG</PNAME>` not for others. Please help

I have tried following vbscript :

```
   Dim oFS      : Set oFS      = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Dim sFSpec   : sFSpec       =        oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("C:\sample.xml")
   Dim objMSXML : Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
   objMSXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
   objMSXML.async = False
   objMSXML.load sFSpec
   objMSXML.validateOnParse = True  
   counter=0
   Set NodeList = objMSXML.documentElement.selectNodes("/ECSC/PARAMETERS/ETPAR_GUIX/item[not(PGROUP)]/PNAME")
  for each item in NodeList
      myPNAME = objMSXML.getElementsByTagName("PNAME").item(counter).text
      If (Left(myPNAME,1)="I") Then
         If objMSXML.getElementsByTagName("PNAME").item(counter).nodeName = "PGROUP"  Then
             msgbox("PGROUP is exist for" &myPNAME)
          Else
              msgbox("PGROUP is NOT exist for" &myPNAME)
         End If
      End If
    counter=counter+1
  Next
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [check particular node is exist or not in XML using vbscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576856/check-particular-node-is-exist-or-not-in-xml-using-vbscript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `NodeList` already contain nodes without corresponding `<PGROUP>`, you don't need to do `If` checking anymore inside `For Each` loop :

```
Set NodeList = objMSXML.documentElement.selectNodes("/ECSC/PARAMETERS/ETPAR_GUIX/item[not(PGROUP)]/PNAME")
For Each item in NodeList
  myPNAME = item.text
  msgbox("PGROUP is NOT exist for" &myPNAME)
Next
```