# check xml node is exist or not using vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript, xml-parsing

This is XML file

```
<ECSC>
 <ATTRIBUTES>
  <some part of attribute section>
 </ATTRIBUTES>
 <SCRIPT>
  <ETXML_LINE_TABTYPE>
     <some part of script section>                 
  </ETXML_LINE_TABTYPE>
 </SCRIPT>
 <PARAMETERS>
  <ETPAR_GUIX>
     <item>
        <PNAME>I_LANG</PNAME>
        <PTYP>I</PTYP>
        <PINDEX>0003</PINDEX>
        <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
        <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
        <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0001</SORT_LNR>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_1</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0009</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>SAPGUI</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>G</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0001</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME2>
        <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>V_LANG</PNAME>
        <PTYP>V</PTYP>
        <PINDEX>0007</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>V.01</PGROUP>
        <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
        <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
        <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0002</SORT_LNR>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_2</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0010</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>SAPGUI</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>G</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0002</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME2>
        <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>I_AGENT</PNAME>
        <PTYP>I</PTYP>
        <PINDEX>0002</PINDEX>

        <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
        <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
        <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0003</SORT_LNR>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_3</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0011</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>GETGUI</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>I</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>GETGUI</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0003</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>GETGUI</PREF_NAME2>
        <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>I_TYPE</PNAME>
        <PTYP>I</PTYP>
        <PINDEX>0004</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>V.04</PGROUP>
        <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
        <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
        <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0004</SORT_LNR>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_4</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0012</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>GETGUI</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>I</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>GETGUI</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0004</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>GETGUI</PREF_NAME2>
        <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>V_AGENT</PNAME>
        <PTYP>V</PTYP>
        <PINDEX>0006</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>I.02</PGROUP>
        <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
        <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
        <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0005</SORT_LNR>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_5</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0013</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>GETGUI</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>I</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>GETGUI</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0005</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>GETGUI</PREF_NAME2>
        <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>V_TYPE</PNAME>
        <PTYP>V</PTYP>
        <PINDEX>0008</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>V.03</PGROUP>
        <PDATLEN>0128</PDATLEN>
        <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
        <PINTLEN>000128</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0006</SORT_LNR>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>WE20_100_STEP_6</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>WE20 - SAPMSEDIPARTNER - 100</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0014</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>SAPGUI</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>G</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0006</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>SAPGUI</PREF_NAME2>
        <VALUE>&lt;VALUE&gt;</VALUE>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>MSG_1</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>Rules for Message Check eCATT Command MESSAGE</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0005</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>MESSAGE</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>M</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>ETMSG_DEF_TABTYPE</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0007</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>ETMSG_DEF_TABTYPE</PREF_NAME2>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>E_MSG_1</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>Collected Messages Before ENDMESSAGE</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0001</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>ENDMESSAGE</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>N</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>ETMSG_RES_TABTYPE</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0008</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>ETMSG_RES_TABTYPE</PREF_NAME2>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
     <item>
        <PNAME>ZX_FI_FP_0569_MS07_COAS_FB_1</PNAME>
        <PTYP>X</PTYP>
        <PDESC>TF_FI_FP_FI_0569_MS07_CO_Search_Help_Internal_Orders_vTD0_1_</PDESC>
        <PINDEX>0015</PINDEX>
        <PGROUP>REF</PGROUP>
        <XMLREF_TYP>R</XMLREF_TYP>
        <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
        <PREF_NAME>ZX_FI_FP_0569_MS07_COAS_FB01</PREF_NAME>
        <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
        <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
        <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
        <SORT_LNR>0009</SORT_LNR>
        <PREF_NAME2>ZX_FI_FP_0569_MS07_COAS_FB01</PREF_NAME2>
        <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
        <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
     </item>
  </ETPAR_GUIX>
```

From above XML file we want to validate following conditions :

1) From `<PARAMETERS>` tag If first two letters of `<PNAME>` tag starts with "I_" OR "V_" OR "E_" Then its corresponding `<PTYP>` and `<PGROUP>` nodetext should be start with "I" OR "V" OR "E" respectively.

2) From `<PARAMETERS>` tag If any of `<PNAME>` does not have its corresponding `<PGROUP>` then VB script should display error and in this situation we have to skip for checking first condition `<PGROUP>` node just display the error " `<PGROUP>` node is not exist for `<PNAME>`"

This is my tried vbscript :

```
Dim oFS      : Set oFS      = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sFSpec   : sFSpec       = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("C:\newXML.xml")
Dim objMSXML : Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
objMSXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
objMSXML.async = False
objMSXML.load sFSpec
objMSXML.validateOnParse = True  
    dim item,items,root
    counter=0 
    Set  NodeList = objMSXML.documentElement.selectNodes("/ECSC/PARAMETERS/ETPAR_GUIX/item")
    for each item in NodeList
        myPNAME = objMSXML.getElementsByTagName("PNAME").item(counter).text
        myPTYP = objMSXML.getElementsByTagName("PTYP").item(counter).text
        myPGROUP = objMSXML.getElementsByTagName("PGROUP").item(counter).text
        If (Left(myPNAME, 2) = "I_") Then
            IsValid_I = True
            If (Left(myPTYP, 1) <> "I") Then
                IsValid_I = False
            End If
            Set pgroup = objMSXML.selectSingleNode("/ECSC/PARAMETERS/ETPAR_GUIX/item[not(PGROUP)]/PNAME")
            If Not pgroup Is Nothing Then
                msgbox("PGROUP is exist for" &myPNAME)
                If (Left(myPGROUP, 1) <> "I" )Then
                    IsValid_I = False
                End If
            Else
                msgbox("PGROUP is not exist for"&myPNAME)
            End If
            If IsValid_I = False Then
                msgbox(myPNAME & " is not valid.")
            End If
            IsValid_I = True
        End If

        If (Left(myPNAME, 2) = "V_") Then
            IsValid_V = True
            If (Left(myPTYP, 1) <> "V") Then
                IsValid_V = False
            End If
            Set pgroup = objMSXML.selectSingleNode("/ECSC/PARAMETERS/ETPAR_GUIX/item[not(PGROUP)]/PNAME")
            If Not pgroup Is Nothing Then
                msgbox("PGROUP is exist for" &myPNAME)
                If (Left(myPGROUP, 1) <> "V" )Then
                    IsValid_V = False
                End If
            Else
                msgbox("PGROUP is not exist for"&myPNAME)
            End If                      
            IsValid_V = False Then
                msgbox(myPNAME & " is not valid.")
            End If
            IsValid_V = True
        End If

        If (Left(myPNAME,2) = "E_") Then
            IsValid_E = True
            If (Left(myPTYP, 1) <> "E") Then
                IsValid_E = False
            End If
            Set pgroup = objMSXML.selectSingleNode("/ECSC/PARAMETERS/ETPAR_GUIX/item[not(PGROUP)]/PNAME")
            If Not pgroup Is Nothing Then
                msgbox("PGROUP is exist for" &myPNAME)
                If (Left(myPGROUP, 1) <> "E" )Then
                    IsValid_E = False
                End If
            Else
                msgbox("PGROUP is not exist for"&myPNAME)
            End If  
            If IsValid_E = False Then
                msgbox(myPNAME & " is not valid.")
            End If
            IsValid_E = True
        End If

    counter=counter+1
next
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use XPath with `selectNodes` to identify the `item` elements that are invalid, then loop through the invalid nodes to display an error message:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim oFS      : Set oFS      = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sFSpec   : sFSpec       = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("C:\doc.xml")
Dim objMSXML : Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
objMSXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
objMSXML.async = False
objMSXML.load sFSpec
objMSXML.validateOnParse = True

FindMissingPgroups objMSXML
FindInvalidPtyps objMSXML
FindInvalidPGroups objMSXML

Sub FindMissingPgroups(doc)
    Dim query, items, item, pname

    query = "/ECSC/PARAMETERS/ETPAR_GUIX/item[not(PGROUP)]"
    Set items = doc.selectNodes(query)

    For Each item In items
        Set pname = item.selectSingleNode("PNAME")
        MsgBox "Missing PGROUP for " & pname.text
    Next ' item
End Sub

Sub FindInvalidPtyps(doc)
    Dim query, items, item, pname, ptyp

    query = query & "/ECSC/PARAMETERS/ETPAR_GUIX/item[PGROUP]["
    query = query & "  (starts-with(PNAME, 'I_') and not(starts-with(PTYP, 'I'))) or "
    query = query & "  (starts-with(PNAME, 'V_') and not(starts-with(PTYP, 'V'))) or "
    query = query & "  (starts-with(PNAME, 'E_') and not(starts-with(PTYP, 'E')))"
    query = query & "]"

    Set items = doc.selectNodes(query)

    For Each item In items
        Set pname = item.selectSingleNode("PNAME")
        Set ptyp = item.selectSingleNode("PTYP")
        MsgBox "Invalid PTYP (" & ptyp.text & ") for " & pname.text
    Next ' item
End Sub

Sub FindInvalidPgroups(doc)
    Dim query, items, item, pname, pgroup

    query = query & "/ECSC/PARAMETERS/ETPAR_GUIX/item[PGROUP]["
    query = query & "  (starts-with(PNAME, 'I_') and not(starts-with(PGROUP, 'I'))) or "
    query = query & "  (starts-with(PNAME, 'V_') and not(starts-with(PGROUP, 'V'))) or "
    query = query & "  (starts-with(PNAME, 'E_') and not(starts-with(PGROUP, 'E')))"
    query = query & "]"

    Set items = doc.selectNodes(query)

    For Each item In items
        Set pname = item.selectSingleNode("PNAME")
        Set pgroup = item.selectSingleNode("PGROUP")
        MsgBox "Invalid PGROUP (" & pgroup.text & ") for " & pname.text
    Next ' item
End Sub
```

A few notes:

- Always use `Option Explicit` at the top of every script. It will save you headaches in the future.
- I split the tests up in three groups rather than two. It's easier to test PTYP and PGROUP separately.
- Notice that the tests for invalid PTYP and PGROUP include a predicate `[PGROUP]`. This ensures that we're only checking items that have a PGROUP (that is part of the requirement for condition 2).

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `For Each` loops, one loop for each rule. For the second rule, select all `<PNAME>` without corresponding `<PGROUP>` and display error message as I already explained in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603453/check-xml-node-exist-or-not-using-vbscript/).

And for the first rule, select all `<item>` with `<PGROUP>` and validate them :

```
Set nodesWithPgroup = objMSXML.documentElement.selectNodes("/ECSC/PARAMETERS/ETPAR_GUIX/item[PGROUP]")
For Each item in nodesWithPgroup
  myPNAME = item.SelectSingleNode("PNAME").text
  myPTYP = item.SelectSingleNode("PTYP").text
  myPGROUP = item.SelectSingleNode("PGROUP").text
  code = Left(myPNAME, 1)
  If (Left(myPNAME, 2) = code & "_") Then
    If (Left(myPTYP, 1) <> code Or Left(myPGROUP, 1) <> code) Then
        msgbox(myPNAME & " is not valid.")
    End If
  End If
Next
```